# C# console app - explicit termination (not Env..Exit)

Tags: c#, console-application

I have heard that on .NET CF Environment.Exit does not work. Is there any universal way how to terminate (in a standard way) the console app? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application automatically terminates when there is no non-background thread running.

A thread automatically stops running when there is no more code to execute.

So, just make your application have no more code to execute when you want it to terminate.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Press a key: ");
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Console.Write("You pressed: 1");
            }
        }
        while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.D2);

    } // <-- application terminates here
}
```

Comment: Yep but that is not explicit termination. The workaround is not difficult (enclose the code with bool) or whatever, but I would like to know the way (if there is) :)

Comment: @Petr: Letting the application end itself is much better than terminating it forcefully. I'm not sure why you'd ever use Environment.Exit.

Comment: What about main menu? Press 1 for start, 2 to exit

Comment: @Petr: Just make your application come to a normal end when the user pressed '2'. No need for Environment.Exit.